# why cypress get me GET error and then send get 200

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, cypress

i have this error in my testing with cypress.

[image: get error cypress]

when i try to testing my app at the en all works, but i don't understand this error.

[image: cypress complete test]

Here my test code:

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

describe('<Login />', ()=>{

    it('<Login />', ()=>{
        cy.visit('/login');
      
        //formulario existe ??? 
        cy.get('[data-cy=formulario')
            .should('exist');
       
            cy.get('[data-cy=btn-login')
                .should('exist')
        //REVISAR INPUTS
        cy.get('[data-cy=email')
            .should('exist');
        
        cy.get('[data-cy=password')
            .should('exist');   
            
        cy.get('[data-cy=email')
            .type('raixa@raixa.com');

        cy.get('[data-cy=password')
            .type('raixa1234');
        
        cy.get('[data-cy=btn-login').click()
        
    });

        
});



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ew07.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxVXR.png
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: This is not the error that cypres produces., it is actually your application throws for a `productos` service. I am sure you will also see this in your browser also when you open network tab.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can see this in network tab, but my doubt is why show two times the same process, the first in red, and then in blue with the correct 200 GET. maybe something is "wrong" in my code? or is the normal process to te req, res, in react with axios....? thanks

Comment: It depends on application behavior. I assume your app makes more than one GET call where the first one failed and 2nd one is successful with 200.